# Why is this regex not working in awk?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have a text file as such:

```
Attribute 1.............. : attribute value
Encode Date............................. : JUL 2007
Attribute 22076.......... : attribute value`
```

I want to extract the `JUL 2007` segment but only when it is preceded by `Encode Date` as JUL 2007 might appear elsewhere in the file.

This regex below works when tested at regexr.com with the PHP interpreter with global and multi-line mode enabled:

`(?<=Encode Date............................. : ).*$`

But running this command gives me no output, what am I missing?

`cat file.txt | awk '/(?<=Encode Date............................. : ).*$/{print $0}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` supports [POSIX extended regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE).  What you are trying to use is a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE). There is no `(?<=...)` ("look-behind assertion") in EREs.

To get the encoding date from the input, consider

```
awk -F ':' '$1 ~ /^Encode Date/ { sub("^ ", "", $2); print $2 }' file
```

This treats each line as `:`-delimited fields.  It picks out the line whose first such field starts with the string `Encode Date` and removes the space at the start of the second field on that line before printing it.

With `sed`, it would be slightly shorter:

```
sed -n '/^Encode Date/s/.*: //p' file
```

This locates the correct line, then deletes everything up to and including the `:` and the immediately following space, and output the modified line.

Or, with an equivalent `sed` operation that tries to modify every line and prints the ones that it modifies successfully,

```
sed -n 's/^Encode Date.*: //p' file
```

If you want to print the whole line (like your last command seems to want to do), then use

```
awk '/^Encode Date/' file
```

or,

```
sed -n '/^Encode Date/p' file
```

or,

```
grep '^Encode Date' file
```

Related:

- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: I guess one could also synthesize a simple lookbehind using the `match` function as `match($0,/PATTERN/) > 0 {print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, but I wanted to avoid matching each individual dot in the data. They would need escaping, unless you do a string match with `index()` and use the search string's length of course... But it's much too fiddly for what they appear to want to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda fair enough - I meant it more as a general comment than specifically for the OP's requirement